# Выборочное заполнение фоном

Tags: css, css3

Как сделать чтобы область в левом нижнем углу не заполнялась  фоновым цветом? https://jsfiddle.net/0xhypez7/1/

Конечно можно вставить туда картинку, но может как нибудь тенями?

```css
.q1 {
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
  background: blue;
}
.q2 {
  float: left;
  margin-top: 120px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 20px;
  background: black;
}
.q2+div {
  float: left;
  margin-top: 150px;
  width: 177px;
  height: 20px;
  background: #000;
  transform: skew(0, 19deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="q1">
<div class="q2"></div>
<div></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
.q1 {
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
  background: blue;
  position: relative;
}
.q2 {
  float: left;
  margin-top: 120px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  outline: 10px soled red;
  border-top: 20px solid black;
  background: #FFF;
}
.q2+div {
  float: left;
  margin-top: 150px;
  width: 177px;
  height: 100px;
  background: #FFF;
  border-top: 20px solid black;
  transform: skew(0, 19deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="q1">
  <div class="q2"></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```